# Bind virtual class member function in base constructor

Tags: c++, class, bind, class-method

The example below shows a base class which binds a virtual member function to fn. On gcc 4.8, a call to fn on a derived class will call the overloaded calculate function. Can anyone explain why this happens? Is this behaviour compiler independend?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base(){
        fn = std::bind(&Base::calculate,this,1);
    }

    virtual int calculate(int value){
        return value + 1;
    }

    std::function<int(int)> fn;  
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Base() {}

    int calculate(int value){
        return 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    Derived test;
    std::cout << test.fn(10) << std::endl;
    /* Output of test.fn(10) is zero, so overloaded function was called */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should this not happen? The expression `&Base::calculate` is a compile time constant - its value can't possibly depend on the context in which it's used. When the member function is called via this pointer, the virtual dispatch happens in the same way as when the function name is used directly.

Comment: There's nothing overloaded in your code. Do you mean "overridden"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code behaves as expected: calling a virtual member function dispatches to the most-overridden function in the most-derived object that contains the instance object of the call. The fact that you're using a member function pointer (inside a bind expression) makes no difference; in fact, the whole point of pointers-to-member-function is that they work correctly with virtual dispatch.

If you want a non-virtual call of the base function, you can do something like this:

```
Base() : fn([this]() { return this->Base::calculate(1); }) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Class member binding is something which is really helpful for my application.